# D3 Throwing "Uncaught Syntax Error: Unexpected Token >" for scripts

Tags: d3.js

I can't seem to get D3 running. I am trying to run this script:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html"; charset="UTF8">
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="d3/d3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="viz"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    w = 500
    h = 300
    x = null
    y = null
    intervalTime = 500

    data = d3.range(100).map((n) -> Math.round(Math.random() * 100))

    setInterval(
        () ->
            data.push(Math.round(Math.random() * 100))
            data.shift()
            calculate_scales()
            redraw()
        , intervalTime)

    calculate_scales = () ->
        x = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, data.length - 1]).range([0, w])
        y = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, d3.max(data)]).range([h, 0])

    calculate_scales()

    vis = d3.select("body")
        .append("svg:svg")
        .attr("width", w)
        .attr("height", h)
        .append("svg:g")

    path = d3.svg.line()
        .x((d, i) -> x(i))
        .y((d) -> y(d))
        .interpolate("linear")

    vis.selectAll("path")
        .data([data])
        .enter()
        .append("svg:path")
        .attr("d", path)

    redraw = () ->
        vis.selectAll("path")
            .data([data])
            .attr("transform", "translate(#{x(1) - x(0)})")
            .attr("d", path)
            .transition()
            .ease("linear")
            .duration(intervalTime)
            .attr("transform", "translate(0)")
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Whenever I open the html in Chrome and look at the developer tools, I get an

> Uncaught SyntaxError:: Unxpected token >

I get this error (syntaxerror on . char) when trying scripts with things like

```
.navigator .data {
    fill: lightgrey;
    stroke-width: 0px;
}
```

as well. I already put the `charset="UTF8"` in the html code. I have no idea what to do here.

Comment: This looks like CoffeeScript. It's not going to work inside a browser without transpiling.

Comment: You can also successfully run your code in jsFiddle by changing the language (in the Languages panel) to Coffeescript: http://jsfiddle.net/henbox/5meeofp7/1/

Comment: Ah this is CofeeScript, but I have also run into problems running js code such as in http://blog.scottlogic.com/2014/09/19/interactive.html (here I get an " Uncaught SyntaxError:: Unexpected token . "